# AngularJS function with parameter undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I have the follwing code on my html:

```
<label style="color:#f0a948; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-stretch: normal; margin-top:5px; margin-right:5px;" ng-click="addNovoComunicado(novo)">

                            </label>

 <label style="border:none; 
                display:block; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: -6px;">
                <span class="input-label" style="font-family: SF UI Display, Roboto, Helvetica;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        font-style: normal;
                        font-stretch: normal;
                        letter-spacing: normal;
                        text-align: left;
                        color: #8d8f95;">Data/Hora</span>
            </label>
            <input type="datetime-local" ng-init="novo = {}" ng-model="novo.dataHora" 
                    style="border: 0;
                    outline: 0;
                    background: transparent;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #8d8f95;
                    margin-top: -10px; color: #011937; width:321px;">



                <label style="border:none; 
                    display:block; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20px;">
                    <span class="input-label" style="font-family: SF UI Display, Roboto, Helvetica;
                            font-size: 14px;
                            font-style: normal;
                            font-stretch: normal;
                            letter-spacing: normal;
                            text-align: left;
                            color: #8d8f95;">Título</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" ng-init="novo = {}" ng-model="novo.titulo" 
                        style="border: 0;
                        outline: 0;
                        background: transparent;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #8d8f95;
                        margin-top: -10px; color: #011937; width:321px;">
```

And in my app.js I have the following code on my Controller:

```
$scope.addNovoComunicado = function(novo){
debugger;
novo.id = $scope.comunicados.length + 1; 
$scope.comunicados.$add(novo);
$state.go('comunicados');
}
```

What happens is that the "novo" parameter of the function is undefined when it is reached.

What can be?

Answer (score 0):

When `addNovoComunicado` invoked with the param meter of `undefined` or `null` the

```
novo.id = $scope.comunicados.length + 1;
```

not possible and the state change also not done.